# MySQL: sort by multiple columns (distance and date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a users table with distance (float) and last online (date).

I want to sort the users by a mix of the two, giving more weight to the online date, so that the result will show users most recently online and then closest to location (smallest distance).

Is this possible with sql? Or is something like elastic search required?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can construct a metric.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
order by 1.0 * abs(distance - @location) + 1.0 * datediff(curdate(), last_online) asc
limit 1
```

The `1.0`s are arbitrary parameters that you can set for your weighting purposes.

Comment: Amazing! That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify more then one column in order by. If I understand your question correct.

```
SELECT
    contactLastname,
    contactFirstname
FROM
    customers
ORDER BY
    contactLastname DESC,
    contactFirstname ASC;
```

Something like that will help you

Read more in: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/